# Two canvases in the same view

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

trying to have to two canvas that i can draw on separately.
Right now i have a relative layout with two views in it. 
Something like:

```
    topHolder = new RelativeLayout(this);
    drawBoard1 = new view(this);
    drawBoard1 = new view(this, gamePanel);
    topHolder.addView(gamePanel);
    topHolder.addView(touchView);
```

That works great, exept that i can only draw to canvas on one of them, if i draw on both, only  1 canvas is showing. 
I get the canvas by using

```
getHolder().canvas
```

But i guess when i use this on to views, it returns the same canvas.
How can i make a "two layer"-view with separate canvases?
Thank you

Comment: If the front canvas is transperant, shouldn't the background canvas appear?

Comment: @Simon The front canvas is never shown if i draw the background canvas after i draw the front canvas. my guess is that the views share the same canvas?

Comment: I am too having the same issue